# AddonsManager startup error with Selenium Webdriver 3.4.0

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have Firefox v53.0.2 
Selenium Webdriver 3.4.0
Geckodriver 0.16.1 installed.

While running test script, I am getting following error:

```
1495619876437   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:27938
1495619876783   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?
\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1495619878148   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... 
"Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) 
[nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  
location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: 
FileUtils_getDir :: lineJavaSc r7i0p"t   edrartoar::  nroe]s oSutraccek: 
/t/rgarcee/:m oFdiulleeUst/iAldsd_ogneMtaDniarg(e)r@.rjessmo,u 
rlce://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:7i0n e<  1F6i5l7e:U 
tNiSl_sE_RgReOtRF_iNlOeT(_)I@NrIeTsIoAuLrIcZeE:D/:/ gArdedonMan/amgoedru 
liess /nFoitl eiUntiitlisa.ljiszme:d4
2
< validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:671 < 
startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:834 < 
startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3129 < 
observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
1495619881253   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 55174
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2570: 
NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
1495619882013   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored 
for this session
May 24, 2017 3:28:02 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: 
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20170515161201/recaptcha__en.js, 
line 372: Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey
```

My Code snippet looks like:

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver.exe");
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver=new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

What is the issue and what needs to be modified? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any significant error as such in your code.

You have taken a good step by setting the `marionette` to "true". But the reason you are seeing the `addons.manager  ERROR` is because you have not suppressed/ignored the `JavaScript` errors. Though these are harmless and you can live with them.

Finally, you shouldn't mention `System.setProperty` twice in your code as you did, as it may induce unnecessary chaos in your Test execution. `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver.exe");`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.